# Android django facebook login

Tags: android, django, facebook, python-social-auth

this is my first project with django and i'm using python social auth to create users with the facebook account's and works fine, now im trying to do the same thing but from android and save information on server, some clue to do this

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried? What errors/crashes are occurring?

Comment: I have facebook registration for android works fine but I don't know how send this information to save or load a user for my application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the documentation regarding that at <strike>http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token</strike> https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token. There you will find a code snippet that will simplify your work, take that snippet as a template where you fill the details related to your project (like the return data, etc).

Edit: updated documentation link.

Comment: This is obsolete now (the link is broken too).